# My validation loss and accuracy are fluctuating a lot. Is there any specific reason for this

Tags: python, keras, graph, conv-neural-network, resnet

[Loss and Accuracy Convergence Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEG89.png)

This is the model I have used:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
include_top=True,
weights=None,
input_tensor=None,
input_shape=(256,256,3),
pooling=None,
classes=10)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=487,
    epochs=15,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=244,
    callbacks = callback_list,
    verbose=1)
```

I am using image generator with batch size of 32 for training and validation set
And augmentation is true for training but false for validation set

Comment: How is your data split? Is it with ```ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=.##)``` or is your data already split. In my experience the validation acc/loss are more variable than training but not usually that much. Does it do the same thing if you set augmentations for validation set?

Comment: The split is 2:1 (Training: Validation ). It is already split and I used two ImageDataGenerators for Training and Validation. I havent set augmentations for validation set thought. I guess I will check it

Comment: Can this be because of BatchNormalization?